# dataclasses: What is the inheritance equivalent of super() .__ init __ ()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these two classes

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, parent_name, parent_age):
        self.parent_name = parent_name
        self.parent_age = parent_age


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, child_name, gender):
        self.child_name = child_name
        self.gender = gender

        
        super().__init__('Miguel', 29)


c = Child('Kevin', 'Male')

c.parent_name
c.parent_age
c.child_name
c.gender
```

I'm trying to implement it with `dataclass`

How to inherit the properties of the parent class to the child

For example:

```
@dataclass
class Parent:
    parent_name: str
    parent_age: int


@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    child_name: str
    gender: str

    # Inherit here
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance

Comment: ... you don't need to do anything this code already does what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`dataclasses` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance) (linked by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) in a comment), the most basic way to make your `Child` class inherit the fields of the `Parent` class **is to do nothing**. The `dataclass` decorator will combine the fields of both classes for you!

The `Child` class will act like it has four fields, starting with the inherited ones from `Parent` and ending with its own. The generated `__init__` method will accept four arguments and initialize things as you'd expect.

If you want to add default values for the inherited fields it's a little bit more tricky, since you'd normally need to provide default values for all the later fields since the inherited ones come first. But you can make it work, if you need to, by overriding the inherited attributes using a `field` with `init=False` so it won't be put into the `__init__` method:

```
from dataclasses import field

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    child_name: str
    gender: str
    parent_name: str = field(default="Miguel", init=False)
    parent_age: str = field(default=29, init=False)
```

One thing I'd caution against given your example code: Make sure that inheritance is really what you want here. It may be that you want your `Child` class to *contain a reference* to a `Parent` object, rather than inheriting from the class. In object oriented programming, inheritance means an *IS-A* relationship between two classes (e.g. that a `Child` *IS-A* `Parent`, which doesn't make much sense). Composition using references, in contrast, models *HAS-A* relationships (e.g. that a `Child` *HAS-A* `Parent`). You may not want to use programming inheritance to represent real-world inheritance relationships!

So the best model of all may be more like this:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    parent: "Person" = None

miguel = Person("Miguel", 39)       # the parent
kevin = Person("Kevin", 0, miguel)  # the child
```